# Rendering Component in Jest Test With Mocks

Tags: react-native, jestjs

**Background**

I am writing some jest test for a React Native application we are writing. In one component I received an error,

> User is not defined.

So I `console.log(user)` in the component and got the output. Then created a mock of the `user`.

*user*

```
module.exports = {
    id: 'ABCDERD',
    name: 'Boss Ninja',
    language: 'en',
};
```

In the component the line that throws the error is this,

```
  const languageName = _.findWhere(languages, { key: this.props.screenProps.user.get('language') }).value;
```

So once I created the mock `user` the error cleared but then I got this error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

I assumed here that I need to create a mock for `get()`. But . am not sure how to call it. If someone would please show me how to handle writing the test for this component to get it to render, I would appreciate it.

This is what I am trying to do,

```
const tree = renderer.create(
    <ProfileScreen screenProps={user} />
);
```

How do I clear the error of `get()` not being defined?

**Example**

User Object

```
module.exports = {
    id: '0052C000000gFJrQAM',
    name: 'My Name',
    language: 'en',
    get: language => language,
    value: 'English (US)',
};
```

Test

```
const tree = renderer.create(
        <ProfileScreen screenProps={{ user }} />
  );
```

**Error**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are trying to access to a property user of screenProps who is undefined. Here user is equal to screenProps as you passed it. What you should do is passing an object to screenProps with a property user because you are calling screenProps.user in your code.

```
const tree = renderer.create(
    <ProfileScreen screenProps={{ user: userMock }} />
);
```

Then you should add get method to your object user. You can return whatever you want for your get method.

```
userMock.get = (language) => { 
    return language;
}
```

Or in your case

```
module.exports = {
    id: '0052C000000gFJrQAM',
    name: 'my name',
    language: 'en',
    get: (language) => {
       return language
    }
};
```

Comment: In your code, you are passing an user to screenProps. Before this you said you have created a mock of the user. The place where you are mocking this user you have to had an attribute get to this user who will be a function like i show you

Comment: You still have the error Cannot read property 'get' of undefined ?